# Async await in console application

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, console-application

Makes any sense to write windows console application asynchronously (using async/await), while it should run sequentially? There are some async candidates methods (calling webservice, loading data to database), but in fact, everything should run step by step. It is just maintenance utility.

Is there any reason to write async code?

Comment: With async you can build in a graceful cancellation of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is strictly a SO question, especially as there's no "right answer", but...

Not so long ago we wouldn't even be asking this question. Just write synchronous code and be done with it. So clearly there's no pressing **need** to write it async but it does, perhaps have a number of benefits.

- As @Silvermind pointed out - you can allow for cancellation
- Might make it easier to allow for better feedback - eg pseudo progress "bars" - such as asterisks across the screen or a percentage counter. Depends on what you're doing.
- Future "proof" (ha ha) - when someone tells you to write a WinForms or WPF application for it because they find it "too difficult to remember all those fiddly command line switches". You've already got the guts of the code.
- Lots of .net libraries are getting the async code added and MS are beginning to treat them as the standard / proper way of approaching a task (pun intended :-) .
- If it's a moderately simple app then you can use it as a good excuse to practice working with async code. Async code is often tricky and so getting practice in writing it never hurts (I think).

And, of course, there's always the old favourite - "because you can"!

If you need to do this app quickly then just knock it out in the time honoured fashion and move on. Otherwise, if you have a little time for it, then build it with all the clever underlying bits and bobs. But, ultimately, don't spend too long worrying about it.

All in my humble opinion, of course.

Comment: If your are printing text after `await` you will need a context to avoid collisions. Otherwiseget this you might

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence - there is a right answer. There may not be a wrong answer, however, as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: @Gusdor - indeed, as I said - async is tricky (and needs practice). However, printing wasn't mentioned and seems less likely in a maintenance app.

Comment: @ErikForbes - Fair enough. But sync or async will both work and get the job done. Without more info we can't say whether one way is right and one wrong. Depends on the wider context I would have thought.

Comment: I agree, it does depend on the context, but given what he's said about context so far, using async for the sake of using async will only add additional complexity without purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to run synchronously, then don't use asynchronous methods.